# Execute code from one textbox and display the output in another textbox in HTML

Tags: javascript

Having two textbox, in first text box i have to write my JAVASCRIPT code and when i click button, want my output in my second text box. I had used the following method its executing the code but the entire page is getting reload and output is getting displayed.

```
<script>
function doIt() {
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
    newScript.type = "text/javascript";
    newScript.innerHTML = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can use `eval`, but it's unsafe. I recommend you to use nodejs to execute and display the result in html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert a  node into the body in order to execute the JS. Instead you can just use eval command. You could do something like this

```
jsVal = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
document.getElementById("textarea2").value = eval(jsVal);
```

Comment: <textarea>                                                                                                       <Button>                                                                                                         <textarea>... So i want to write document.write("JS") in textarea1 and after clicking i want JS[output] in the second textarea